# Set an output variable from an agentless job

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-tasks

I have a pipeline that runs an [agentless job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#agentless-tasks). This job produces a result that I would like to pass to the next or next job. The problem is that all the examples I've found set variables on agent jobs, not agentless. [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-pipeline), all the examples use script commands, which need to be run on an agent.

Is there a way to set an output variable from an agentless job? How else can I pass the result from an agentless job to the next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting output variables from agentless jobs isn't supported

> powershell runs Windows PowerShell and will only work on a Windows agent.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops

Depending on what your use-case is, you may be able to use `dependsOn` and `condition` in your jobs to achieve your goal. E.g. for retries for builds that are not idempotent. Otherwise an agent-based configuration may be needed.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to pass a value to the next task. If it would be a pass-fail type of step, a `dependsOn`  would work.